# any pointers on deploying app on ios devices for beta testing

Tags: ios, deployment

This is my first app and its ready to be deployed on devices. going through apple's 100 or 150 page "App Distribution Guide" is plain daunting. I'm using xcode 5 and iOS sdk 7.0 and I signed up for ios developer membership. is there any any web page giving a walk through of deploying it? how to create icons, how many and how to specify them in app etc. appreciate that.

I ran into testflight but they are no longer accepting new signups.

Comment: Do some searching on AdHoc deployment.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply prepare AdHoc builds which your beta-testers can install on their devices via iTunes. Actually, UDIDs of their devices must be in corresponding provisioning profile which you use to create this builds.